# Ruby - Help with array literals

Tags: ruby

I know how to do this:

```
%w(doc ppt xls).include?(fileext)
```

I now need something similar but the match terms have spaces in them. I've tried

```
%w("blah blah" "yada yada" "wowowow").include?(actiontype)
```

Goal here is to see if actiontype exists inside one of the quotes or not. Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
["blah blah", "yada yada", "wowowow"].include?(actiontype)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
["blah blah", "yada yada", "wowowow"].include?(actiontype)
```

Or, you could choose to escape spaces.

```
%w(blah\ blah yada\ yada wowowow).include?(actiontype)
```

This second example really only makes sense when you rarely have a space, like:

```
%w(yellow red blue orange green black dark\ blue purple).include?(color)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an exact match, just use an array.

```
["blah blah", "yada yada", "wowowow"].include?(actiontype)
```

If it's something else that you're looking for, please ask a more specific question and include an example input and desired output.